# Drawing .mtl files in Directx

Tags: c++, directx

So I've created my own obj loader and it loads normal's, UV's, vertices, indices and faces.. but it will only draw the whole obj a single color. I would like my loader to display the model as if it were in blender. So my question is how do i use the material file to give my model its "color".. the material file doesn't say very much nor anything i find useful, soooo do i have more work to do to create a texture out of each side or?... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Typical use-case would be to write a Blinn-Phong shader and use .mtl's ambient, diffuse and specular values there. .mtl also gives you the texture file name.